# Running API Exception handling

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I attempt to run my API after scaffolding, I get this error in my `program.cs` file:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\API_YES\appsettings.json'.'

at my

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Can anyone please assist what to do to fix this?

Comment: check your appsettings.json file is in the project directory and add this code 
    **builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");** and select appsettings in properties select copy always i solved this problem once maybe its helps you

Comment: could you pls help check if the appsettings.json file is in `C:\Users\User\Downloads\API_YES\appsettings.json'`? Or in somewhere else, e.g. `C:\Users\User\Downloads\API_YES\API_YES\appsettings.json'`